# ARM9 vs ARM11 performance?

Tags: arm, cpu, mips, arm9, performance

This may be a loaded question, but is there a general understanding of the performance increase per clock between ARM9 and ARM11? Say, for a math-heavy function (FFT)?

Thanks!

Comment: No reason to put in on hold. The one answer was a perfect answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look at this [link](http://www.pengutronix.de/development/kernel/arm-benchmarks-20100729_en.html). It compares ARM9, ARM11 ARM Cortex A8, Xscale & Atom processors based on floating point multiplication, memory bandwidth, context switching time, sysstem call performance, process forking, etc.

Hope this will help you.:)

Comment: Great. That's better than I was hoping for :)